# To which specific Microsoft Windows patch does this InfoWorld article claim is being implicated in increased snooping?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, windows-update, privacy

In this [excellent InfoWorld article by Woody Leonhard](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3115766/microsoft-windows/blame-microsoft-not-users-for-fragmented-patching-in-windows-7-and-81.html), Woody states that there is a possible patch to resolve Microsoft's Windows Update taking eight hours to just check for updates.  Woody writes:

> Back in June, we saw a harbinger of this new technique. As I [explained at the time](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3086811/microsoft-windows/microsoft-releases-kb-3161647-kb-3161608-to-fix-slow-windows-7-update-scans.html), you could get a new patch that would speed up Windows 7 update scans, but in order to install it, you had to install six completely unrelated patches -- at least one of which has been implicated in increased snooping.

Upon reading the initial article, as well as [the article referenced in the above quote](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3086811/microsoft-windows/microsoft-releases-kb-3161647-kb-3161608-to-fix-slow-windows-7-update-scans.html), I do not see it mentioned which **Microsoft Windows patch has been implicated in increased snooping**.  Unfortunately, it must be said, that Microsoft has been publishing many patches that reportedly contain code that performs snooping behavior; but for **this question, I am asking to which *specific* patch the above quote refers**.

Bonus: For that *specific* patch, is there any information to confirm or deny the alleged snooping behavior?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Please read the above question.  It is not a duplicate of that other question.  It asks a *very specific* question that is different from that other question.

Comment: "possible patch to resolve Microsoft's Windows Update taking eight hours to just check for updates. " this is what the duplink tells you to solve.

Comment: @magicandre1981 And that is **NOT** the question being asked above.  Please read again.

Comment: @magicandre1981 The question above is about the 6 completely unrelated patches to that issue, one of which has allegedly been implicated in increased snooping.  Your flag is erroneous.